# $_GET always returning null

Tags: php, wordpress, get, query-string

I have a Wordpress site calling a .php file on our server using a shortcode.  The goal is to return query parameters to a Wordpress form using hidden fields.

Here is the problem:  $_GET['param'] doesn't seem to work for any key 'param'.  For example, I have the following code in my shortcode function:

```
ChromePhp::log('Test Output');
ChromePhp::log($_GET['test']);
ChromePhP::log($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

I have installed a PHP logging plugin so I can see the PHP output from the Chrome javascript console.  When I go to the URL mysite.com/properpage?test=testparam
The output is:

```
Test Output
null
null
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but when I go to the url with the proper query params (?test=testparam), the url resets itself and clears the query params off the end.

I feel like I'm missing something simple.  Or Wordpress may be blocking query params somewhere for this page so it clears the url?

As suggested by steve in the comment, I added the following to the functions.php file where my shortcode function is:

```
add_action('init','wpse46108_register_param');
function wpse46108_register_param() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('test'); 
}
```

But

```
ChromePhp::log(get_query_var('test'));
```

still has empty output when I add the query param ?test=test.

Comment: Is your Wordpress set up to use permalinks / friendly URLs? If so it may be that parameters are not being passed over... 

try using the method described on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46108/wordpress-and-get-params

Comment: We do use permalinks.. day & name format.  Seems like this solution may be on the right track but it still didn't fix it.  I updated the question to describe what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Use  get_query_var() function to fetch query string variables